# Javascript innerHTML loses css imports

Tags: javascript, styles, innerhtml

When i use innerHTML function, it works perfectly. But it's like it doesn't care about css style.

Example:

```
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

So I use:

```
<div id="container">Something</div>
```

and it does apply the style.
But if i do this through javascript innerHTML, it does not load the style. 
Basically, javascript innerHTML does not follow the css style rules included in my homepage.
Why?

Another example:

```
<ul data-role="listview"><li>Something</li></ul>
```

everything displayed here , has a styled format.

Now, if i do this:

```
var output = document.getElementById("output");
output.innerHTML = '<ul data-role="listview">';
output.innerHTML = '<li>Something</li>';
output.innerHTML = '</ul>';
```

I don't get the same result but a normal list with default formattation instead of my styled one.

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: javascript innerHTML does not follow the css style rules included in my homepage.

Comment: i updated the main post

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [**document.createElement**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)  to create new element [**appendChild**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) to append the a child content.

Here `li` is child of `ul` which in turn is also a child of `div#output`

Hope this snippet will be useful

```
var _ul = document.createElement('ul');
var _li=  document.createElement('ul');

_li.innerHTML="Something";
_ul.appendChild(_li);
document.getElementById("output").appendChild(_ul);
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/hLznb9L9/)

Comment: this is not working if i have to create <ul data-role="listview"> and <li data-icon="false">...

Comment: also, how do i loop <li data-icon="false"> inside <ul data-role="listview"> ?

Comment: your original question does not contain anything about data-role & data-icon .check setAttribute method of javascript

Comment: can you tell me how to use your code to loop <li> tags inside <ul> tags?

Comment: EDIT: solved with cloneNode(true) . But at the end of all, i keep having the same problem. This ul and li override the styled ul and li with the default formatting.